# XMLシンタックスハイライトの不具合

Tags: バグ, 完了, シンタックスハイライト

[XAMLのStyle.Triggersで複合条件を指定したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/7653/xaml%E3%81%AEstyle-triggers%E3%81%A7%E8%A4%87%E5%90%88%E6%9D%A1%E4%BB%B6%E3%82%92%E6%8C%87%E5%AE%9A%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84)の回答を見ていて気が付いたのですが、

```xml
<Style.Triggers>
    <MultiTrigger>
    </MultiTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

が`lang-xml`で正しくハイライトされないようです。

なおルート要素のピリオドを取り除くと動作します。

```xml
<Style_Triggers>
    <MultiTrigger>
    </MultiTrigger>
</Style_Triggers>
```

Comment: 開発者は現在今確認中です。情報があれば、提供します。

Comment: @jmac ハイライトエンジンとして使われている、[Google Code Prettifyのバグ](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=280)のようです。

Comment: @ento ありがとうございます。そうですね。Google側にあれば、解決方法はないと思いますが、念のため、確認します。

Comment: 補足: 上で ento さんが言及なさっている issue は現在 Google Code から GitHub に移植されています: https://github.com/google/code-prettify/issues/280

Comment: @nekketsuuu さん> 当該リポジトリは既にメンテナンスされていないようですが、この問題は現在も再現していますか？（見る限り違和感はありませんが...）

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353983/341401 によってシンタックスハイライトの仕組みが Prettify から highlight.js に変わったので、その影響かもしれません。

Answer (score 6):

どこかのタイミングで、この問題は無くなっていたようです。

2020 年 9 月にシンタックスハイライトの仕組みが Prettify から highlight.js に変わっているので、もしかするとこのタイミングかもしれません: [Goodbye, Prettify. Hello highlight.js! Swapping out our Syntax Highlighter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353983/341401)

以下 2021 年 5 月現在のスクリーンショットです。

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

このバグは当サイトのバグではなく、[entoさんのコメント](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1751/xml%e3%82%b7%e3%83%b3%e3%82%bf%e3%83%83%e3%82%af%e3%82%b9%e3%83%8f%e3%82%a4%e3%83%a9%e3%82%a4%e3%83%88%e3%81%ae%e4%b8%8d%e5%85%b7%e5%90%88#comment878_1751)による[Google Code Prettifyのバグ](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=280)のようです。

Google Prettify上にバグが直した場合、当サイトにも適用します。